# How can I animate an image and adjust the animation speed?

Tags: c++, animation

I am trying to animate an image.

Each time my entire render scene occurs, it cycles to the next image in the animation.

I need to slow/speed it down/up to an arbitrary value.

What's the usual procedure for doing this?

This is what I've tried so far:

**FrameTime.h**

```
static class FrameTime
{
public:
    FrameTime();

    static int current;
    static int max;
    static int step;

    static void Update();
};
```

**FrameTime.cpp**

```
int FrameTime::current = 0;
int FrameTime::max = 100;
int FrameTime::step = 1;

void FrameTime::Update()
{
    if( current >= max )
    {
        current = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        current += step;
    }
}
```

**How the Update function is called:**

```
// Game Render function starts
...
FrameTime::Update();
// Game Render function ends
```

**How I work out if my player animation should update:**

```
void PlayerStateFlying::Update()
{

    if( FrameTime::current % 2 )
    {
        current = sequence[ index ];
        if( index == ( sequenceAmount - 1 ) )
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the code above doesn't allow me to have float precision speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

- define a variable `fps` that keeps the number of frame per seconds the animation has to move at
- start calculating the time passed each frame and store it in `delta` as milliseconds
- declare a variable `total` and start incrementing it with `delta` every frame
- every frame, after the incrementing of `total`, check if `(1000 / fps > total)`,

  - if it is, then its time to move the animation of `total / (1000 / fps)` frames and update total to `fmod(total, (1000 / fps))`
  - otherwise, just continue

Comment: Thanks man, I tried doing this, but now you put it so simply.. boo yaka shann.. let me just implementareeno

Comment: @James Animating by delta time is by far the easiest way. You want your animations to be frame-independent because the models/textures will have different FPS than the game. So you can say, I have 10 images, let's play them 1 second at a time. With delta time, it's as simple as showing a frame with a counter that's incremented by delta time.

Comment: Does this mean that I would skip some animation sequence in some cases?

Comment: @james What I'm saying is, you can easily control your animations if they're frame-independent.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you get some understanding of how physics can be applied

[Physics Engine in Game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLGsZhqPyVE)

[Wiki Pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)

To handle the speed of objects, which in other ways it means to control the movement of objects you need to implement Newtonian Dynamics. Which is described by three laws of motion:

1. A body will remain at rest, or continue moving in a straight path, until a force has been acted upon it
2. The acceleration of the body is proportional to and in same direction of the coming as the net force.
3. For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

The first law means: An object will change its velocity if and only if another force is added to it or applied to it.Example: if a ball is moving in a straight line, it will keep moving in a straight line, until external force is applied to it. Now this external can be anything, which it could be the wind that slows it down or through the friction.

The Second law means: when a force is applied to a body, it changes the objects speed, the second law defines that change:

The third law means: If you punch the wall, the wall will react by applying a force against you. So the action was punching the wall, the reaction was the wall applying a force against you.

---

To implement the law in games, we use numerical integration ( deals with position and acceleration of objects)

Most used one is Semi-Implicit Euler integration

dt is the time passed since last frame.

```
    NextVelocity = ThisVelcoity + CurrentAcceleration * dt;
    NextPosition = ThisPosition +  NextVelocity * dt;
```